# How to handle a button press that isn't triggering the "click" event?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm writing a Google Chrome extension for Google Classroom. It's fairly straightforward: when you press the turn in button, an alert box pops up to remind the user to email their teacher if they're turning in the assignment with a homework extension. This is simply for a friend with ADHD who tends to forget to email their teacher.

I have the Chrome extension working so it runs on the proper page, finds the object, and then adds an event listener for a click. I also have this set for keyDown, as it seems Google went with ARIA. When I use `document.querySelectorAll('[guidedhelpid="turnInButton"]')[0].click()`, it works perfectly. Everything goes as planned. However, when I actually click on the button itself on its own, this doesn't work. I'm at a loss of what to do as I'm nowhere near a web developer, I just wanted to help a friend out.

**NOTE:**

- I did notice that in `jsaction` it does say `preventMouseEvents`, but manually toggling it doesn't seem to alleviate the problem.

checker.js

```js
function remind() {
    alert("Don't forget to email your teacher if you need to use your homework extension!");
}

var t;
var x;

function checker() {
    x = document.querySelectorAll('[guidedhelpid="turnInButton"]')[0];

    if(x) {
        window.clearTimeout(t);
        x.addEventListener('click', remind);
        x.addEventListener('keyDown', remind);
    } else {
        t = window.setTimeout(checker, 100);

    }
}

checker();
```

manifest.json

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "******'s Remind Thingy",
    "description": "This is to remind ****** to email her teachers when she uses her homework extension.",
    
    "version": "1.0",

    "permissions": ["activeTab", "*://classroom.google.com/*"],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "images/icon_128.png"
    },

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "run_at": "document_end",
            "matches": ["*://classroom.google.com/*/a/*"],
            "js": ["remind.js"]
        }
    ],

    "icons": {
        "16": "images/icon_16.png",
        "48": "images/icon_48.png",
        "128": "images/icon_128.png"
    }
}
```

The specific tag I'm grabbing

```html
<div jsshadow="" role="button" class="uArJ5e TuHiFd UQuaGc Y5sE8d M9Bg4d" jscontroller="VXdfxd" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef" jsname="sFeBqf" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" guidedhelpid="turnInButton">
    <div class="Fvio9d MbhUzd" jsname="ksKsZd" style="top: 8px; left: 121.5px; width: 252px; height: 252px;"></div><div class="e19J0b CeoRYc"></div>
    <span jsslot="" class="l4V7wb Fxmcue">
        <span class="NPEfkd RveJvd snByac">Turn in</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When `role=button` onsubmit is also being called so:

```
function remind() {
    alert("Don't forget to email your teacher if you need to use your homework extension!");
return false;
}
...

 x.addEventListener('click',function(){ return remind();} );
```

or remove `role=button` .

Comment: I didn't know about the submit, so thank you for that, but it still didn't end up helping. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: put your script at the bottom of the page because when it is at the beginning the when browser processing  the script, elements do not exist  at that time.

Comment: The problem right now isn't adding the event listener. It's that when I click on the actual button, the event is not triggered.